# Making comparison plots with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data:

```
Z   Dens, Mag Field Dens(2/3), Mag Field    Int Energy, Mag Field   Veloc, Mag Field
11.98021332 0.71309 0.913464    0.0616413   0.0688992
10.97564329 0.647386    0.851829    0.0201593   0.0521511
9.996590466 0.703017    0.818165    0.0221478   0.0364741
9.002339854 0.68228 0.76442 0.0139188   0.0279246
8.012172949 0.716888    0.728804    0.00593295  0.0252737
7.005417046 0.834427    0.727827    0.00475593  0.0104319
6.010757399 0.738236    0.6537  0.00516123  0.00748243
4.995933468 0.523733    0.585724    0.00402287  0.0150163
4.007945111 0.611633    0.779818    0.0036263   0.0305052
3.008131072 0.406155    0.666162    0.000874259 0.0536957
2.002028139 0.625887    0.772948    -0.00245864 0.0804465
1.495512167 0.564005    0.770283    -0.00447156 0.0839212
0.9972942258    0.438992    0.727305    -0.00776316 0.0898124
0.7001063537    0.52024 0.779515    -0.00691212 0.0939644
0.5030475232    0.36599 0.722321    -0.0108507  0.0768843
0.3999269646    0.511343    0.779391    -0.0087712  0.0708183
0.2977176845    0.57282 0.803934    -0.00493039 0.0862836
0.1972841824    0.414532    0.719011    -0.00802562 0.0734819
0.09940180263   0.462694    0.762545    -0.00753659 0.0699443
```

I want to make comparison plots with column Z as the x axis and the following columns as the Y axis with GNUPLOT.
The exact float values should be present along the axis, and appropriate legends.

Please help me with this.

I have been able to make individual plots with

plot 'filename.tsv' using 0:1 with lp

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of data - they are really hard to plot. Just copy the data and paste it into your question and format as code using `{}` button in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*. Please also show your best attempt at code so far and your expected output - even if only a representative sketch.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for your feedback. I have made the corrections. I am very new to GNUPLOT and have been trying this since the last few days. The output I require is similiar to the one in this link https://www.goodly.co.in/line-chart-total/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reformat your first row like this:

```
"Z Dens" "Mag Field Dens(2/3)" "Mag Field" "Int Energy" "Mag Field Veloc" "Mag Field"
```

to let gnuplot recognize the title. Also you need to add this line:

```
set key autotitle columnhead
```

and plot:

```
set xlabel "Z Dens"
plot "a.dat" u 1:2 w lp, "" u 1:3 w lp, "" u 1:4 w lp, "" u 1:5 w lp
```

[image]

Maybe your plot will look better with a log X scale:

```
set logscale x
replot
```

[image]